# How to do a condition check in a dict comprehension?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary d1 and a list l:

```
d1 = {'a':'1', 'b':2, 'c':3}
l = ['a','b','d']

d2 = {e:d1[e] for e in l}
```

Since d is not in d1, so I need to add a condition check for d2 to work. If e is not in d1, I would always put the pair:

```
e:0
```

into d2, so d2 would be

```
{'a':'1', 'b':2, 'd':0}
```

How to add a condition check to this line to get the result:

```
d2 = {e:d1[e] for e in l}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is:

```
{k: (d1[k] if k in d1 else 0) for k in l}
```

Nicer is to use `dict.get`:

```
{k: d1.get(k, 0) for k in l}
```